# Moving down columns in data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have the next data frame:

```
df<-data.frame(step1=c(1,2,3,4),step2=c(5,6,7,8),step3=c(9,10,11,12),step4=c(13,14,15,16))

  step1 step2 step3 step4
1     1     5     9    13
2     2     6    10    14
3     3     7    11    15
4     4     8    12    16
```

and what I have to do is something like the following:

```
df2<-data.frame(col1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12),col2=c(5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16))

   col1 col2
1     1    5
2     2    6
3     3    7
4     4    8
5     5    9
6     6   10
7     7   11
8     8   12
9     9   13
10   10   14
11   11   15
12   12   16
```

How can I do that? consider that more steps can be included (example, 20 steps).

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can design a function to achieve this task. `df_final` is the final output. Notice that `bin` is an argument that the users can specify how many columns to transform together.

```
# A function to conduct data transformation
trans_fun <- function(df, bin = 3){
  # Calculate the number of new columns
  new_ncol <- (ncol(df) - bin) + 1
  # Create a list to store all data frames
  df_list <- lapply(1:new_ncol, function(num){
    return(df[, num:(num + bin - 1)])
  })
  # Convert each data frame to a vector
  dt_list2 <- lapply(df_list, unlist)
  # Convert dt_list2 to data frame
  df_final <- as.data.frame(dt_list2)
  # Set the column and row names of df_final
  colnames(df_final) <- paste0("col", 1:new_ncol)
  rownames(df_final) <- 1:nrow(df_final)
  return(df_final)
}

# Apply the trans_fun
df_final <- trans_fun(df)

df_final
   col1 col2
1     1    5
2     2    6
3     3    7
4     4    8
5     5    9
6     6   10
7     7   11
8     8   12
9     9   13
10   10   14
11   11   15
12   12   16
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the work:

`df2 <- data.frame(col1 = 1:(length(df$step1) + length(df$step2)))
df2$col1 <- c(df$step1, df$step2, df$step3)
df2$col2 <- c(df$step2, df$step3, df$step4)`

Things to point:

- The important thing to see in the first line of the code, is the need for creating a table with the right amount of rows
- Calling a columns that does not exist will create one, with that name
- Deleting columns in R should be done like this df2$col <- NULL

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method using `dplyr` and `reshape2` - this assumes all of the columns are the same length.

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
```

Drop the last column from the dataframe

```
df[,1:ncol(df)-1]%>% 
    melt() %>% 
    dplyr::select(col1=value) -> col1
```

Drop the first column from the dataframe

```
df %>%
    dplyr::select(-step1) %>% 
    melt() %>% 
    dplyr::select(col2=value)  -> col2
```

Combine the dataframes

```
bind_cols(col1, col2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you not just looking to do:

```
df2 <- data.frame(col1 = unlist(df[,-nrow(df)]), 
                  col2 = unlist(df[,-1]))
rownames(df2) <- NULL
df2
```

> ```
>    col1 col2
> 1     1    5
> 2     2    6
> 3     3    7
> 4     4    8
> 5     5    9
> 6     6   10
> 7     7   11
> 8     8   12
> 9     9   13
> 10   10   14
> 11   11   15
> 12   12   16
> ```